# Por que meu xmlhttp.status retorna zero?

Tags: javascript, html, json, xmlhttprequest

Estou com um problema em meu [html](/questions/tagged/html), tento pegar um json, mas o `xmlhttp.status` sempre está 0(zero). Pesquisei a respeito, porém não achei nada muito concreto.

Abaixo, simplifiquei o código para evidenciar o problema:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Meu Projeto</h1>

<button onclick="math()">Current Math</button>
<div id="teste"></div>
<div id="status"></div>
<div id="readystate"></div>
<script>
identificador = 0;

function math(){
  
var url = "https://br.api.pvp.net/observer-mode/rest/consumer/getSpectatorGameInfo/BR1/974721?api_key=5";
  
document.getElementById("teste").innerHTML = "URL: " + url;
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Status: " + xmlhttp.status;
document.getElementById("readystate").innerHTML = "ReadyState: " + xmlhttp.readyState;
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
     alert("OK tudo certo");
    }

    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 404) {
     alert("Erro 404");
    }
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 0) {
     alert("status 0????");
    }
  }
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Já reparou que esse não ocorre no IE?

Comment: Você usa qual linguagem de programação?

Comment: No IE está funcionando.